# specify Atspi version before import

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I use [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2155281) python library which uses pyatspi (`from pyatspi import …`). When I run it in (L)Ubuntu 16.04, it throws the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyatspi/__init__.py:17: PyGIWarning: Atspi was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Atspi', '2.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Atspi
```

Although this error message says exactly what I should do to, it doesn't work just to add the line `gi.require_version('Atspi', '2.0')` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyatspi/__init__.py` (giving `NameError: name 'gi' is not defined`) – what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's necessary to import `require_version` from `gi` first, so just add:

```
from gi import require_version
require_version('Atspi', '2.0')
```

before the

```
from gi.repository import Atspi
```

line in the file given by the error message, which was `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyatspi/__init__.py` here.